# Syntax in ng-style & merging ng-styles

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-style in my project that looks like:

```
ng-style="{'background-color':(headerObj.inEditBool?'background-color: rgba(101, 182, 231, 0.11);':headerObj.confirmedOrSkipBool?'white':'rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.3)')}"
```

I want a second attribute of the element (border color) to be affected in the same statement... How can I add that change?

```
ng-style="{'border-color':(headerObj.inEditBool?'border-color: #65B6E7;':headerObj.confirmedOrSkipBool?'#DFE3E9;':'#E06A62;')}"
```

This is the border color I want to make a change to. **How to merge 2 ng-styles so I can affect the background color and border color of the same element?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another property to the style object:

```
  {
    'background-color':(headerObj.inEditBool?'rgba(101, 182, 231, 0.11)':headerObj.confirmedOrSkipBool?'white':'rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.3)'),
    'border-color':(headerObj.inEditBool?' #65B6E7':headerObj.confirmedOrSkipBool?'#DFE3E9':'#E06A62')
  }
```

I don't like using multiple tertiary operators like that, it's difficult to read and hard to update. I'd break it out into a function instead. Also, I don't think you need the semicolons either. edit2: the object property name is where you list the style name, you also had it in the property value, I don't think that works.